# What's the difference between DENetworkDataset and NetworkDataset in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects

In ArcObjects, there are two Coclasses which are similar with each other: `DENetworkDataset`  and  `NetworkDataset`  , and `GetDataElementFromNetworkDataset` can transform NetworkDataset to DENetworkDataset, which is:

```
    IDENetworkDataset GetDataElementFromNetworkDataset(INetworkDataset networkDataset)
    {
      IDatasetComponent datasetComponent = networkDataset as IDatasetComponent;
      return (datasetComponent.DataElement as IDENetworkDataset);
    }
```

However, what's the difference between these two datasets?

Answer (score 1):

The `DENetworkDataset` is a light weight object that holds information about a network dataset.

If you check the ESRI documentation about [IDENetworkDatase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDENetworkDataset.htm) and [INetworkDataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#INetworkDataset.htm) you can see that the first provides access to members that describe network dataset data elements and the second one provides access to members that query the schema of the network dataset.

They have different properties and methods, so it depends what do you want to do.